# MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration not applying to alias SMTP addresses

Tags: exchange, auto-reply, shared-mailbox

We have a department that requires a Shared Mailbox. Previously there were multiple Public Folders that were setup for this work. Because they want to Share, Send As, & send an Auto-reply from the account (which you can't do all three in a Public Folder) a Shared Mailbox was created and the addresses from the other Public Folders were added to it so that it would now funnel all new mail to the one location. The problem is the auto-reply only fires when an email is sent to the main email address, not the additional SMTP addresses. We receive email to both the old and the new addresses, however the sender only receives an auto-reply from the new address. Supposedly I can use MFCMapi to review the responses, but I can't seem to get it to work with a Shared Mailbox (no password--no login.)

I can't find any documentation in my search that says an AutoReply response will only initiate from the primary mail address. So I'm posting here in hopes that someone else has run across this.

The AutoReply Configuration is listed below:

```
    PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -Identity [Shared Mailbox]
    

    RunspaceId       : 1fa53a7a-c08a-4527-802b-5c007a21d7ae
    AutoReplyState   : Enabled
    EndTime          : 8/26/2022 11:00:00 AM
    ExternalAudience : All
    ExternalMessage  : <html>
               <body>
               <b>Your email was received by the designated [department], [my company]<br>
               <br>
               <br>
               <br>
               Thank you,<br>
               <br>
               [my company name] </b>
               </body>
               </html>
               
    InternalMessage  : 
    StartTime        : 8/25/2022 11:00:00 AM
    MailboxOwnerId   : [domain.com]/[department]/[ID]
    Identity         : [domain.com]/[department]/[ID]
    IsValid          : True
    ObjectState      : Unchanged
```

Answer (score 0):

Never seen this issue before.
But you can try to follow below steps to set the auto reply in EAC.

1. Go to EAC and select another mailbox.

[image]

2. Set up an automatic reply message.

[image]

Comment: How's everything going now? If the issue has been solved, please do not forget to mark helpful reply as an answer. THANKS!

Comment: This shows me the Auto reply that was already built. I've found no way to differentiate between the main address and the other SMTP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply. According to my test, the answer is no. The issue is caused by the reply address.

Basically, one mailbox can have multiple email addresses. BUT it can only have ONE reply address. You need to change the reply address so that it will send from the secondary email address which you want.

Maybe you can create a new mailbox with the secondary email address. Then assign full access permission to the default mailbox. Create some rule in outlook or somewhere such as when userb receive an email then usera will send an auto reply for him. I don’t know. Maybe it works as an workaround.

Comment: How's everything going now?